# Почему FileOutputStream Java записывает символы, а не байты?

Tags: java, io

Почему я вижу в файле текст (символы), а не байтовое представление этих символов когда пишу этот код:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
fileOutputStream.write(symbol);
```

Но этот код:

```
System.out.println(symbol);
```

выводит на консоль то, что мне нужно.
И как записать в файл байтовое представление этих символов?

Comment: что такое `symbol`? Что значит `я вижу в файле текст`?

Comment: `symbol` какого типа?

Comment: я считал с помощью ...new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...)) символ из текстового файла методом read() и хочу его записать в другой текстовый файл и ожидаю увидеть в нём код символа, а не сам символ. symbol типа int если я правильно понимаю

Comment: Если вы пишете символ в файл, почему вы рассчитываете увидеть код символа при чтении? Пишите код символа в файл и читайте код символа.

Comment: Ведь FileOutputStream это поток вывода байтов, а в файле появляются символы (всмысле те которые я считал символьным потоком ввода InputStreamReader), вот я и ожидаю увидеть байтовые коды в файле на который направлен поток вывода.

Comment: А если просто написать `fileOutputStream.write(Integer.toString(symbol).getBytes())`, то будет ли это похоже на желаемый результат?

Comment: @BccHnw спасибо, помог. А как записать в двоичном представлении эти же значения?